# How to ssh from powershell?

Tags: ssh, shell, powershell

How to ssh from powershell? Basically from my host-os windows7 to my guest-os linux.

Comment: none of these answers address how to initiate a connection from powershell itself...

Answer (score 3):

Install an SSH client and start it?

Answer (score 0):

There is [putty utility called PLINK](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)
Usage:

```
$out = .\plink.exe -ssh $($hostIP) -l $($attribute_user) -pw $($attribute_password) -batch super cat /etc/opt/somefile_or_any_other_command
```

You have to sotre SSL certificate of remote server before first connection. This can be done by:

```
echo Y | .\plink.exe -ssh $($hostIP) -l $($attribute_user) -pw $($attribute_password) exit
```